# Deploying external html file within GitHub pages

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, jupyterbook

I am trying to deploy a GitHub pages instance with a Jupyterbook inside that. That runs smoothly without any problem. But I also need to deploy a Python kernel and I can manage that with using Thebe.

Now, my problem is that; I cannot host Thebe instance inside the Jupyterbook, so I do it as an external page in the *ghpages* branch of my GitHub repository. But everytime the page is reployed, I have to manually push the html file.

Is there a way to omit the redeployment for this external html file?